# How to I compare a date in saved string format to current date when querying data from firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Firestore Db]

I have a field for dates in every document I create in a particular collection. The data for this date field is saved as a string. When a perform a query, I want to compare the date field to the current date via a `whereField()` method property in firebase so as the to get the documents that agree with this comparison.

I have tried some code below but it does not do exactly what is required.
Data in date field is saved in the format `eventDate: "Fri Aug 30 2019"`

```
   let db = Firestore.firestore()

   let date = Date.init()

   let formatter = DateFormatter()

   formatter.dateStyle = .long
   formatter.timeStyle = .none
   formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
   formatter.dateFormat = "eee MMM dd yyyy"

   let currDate = formatter.string(from: date)

   db.collection("Events").whereField("eventDate", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: currDate).getDocuments() {
   // completion code not necessary for this question
```

The code above returns only events occurring on `Tue Aug 27 2019` & `Wed Aug 28 2019` well knowing there are more dates on which events are to occur.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Using calendar components should be a better approach, something like this?

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()

let calendar = Calendar.current
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())
let currDate = calendar.date(from: components)!

db.collection("Events").whereField("eventDate", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: currDate).getDocuments()
```

Comment: How is it different from what I dried earlier ?

Comment: in your code, currDate is a string; with my modifications, currDate is a Date isnt it?

Comment: My currDate is a string because the "eventDate" value is a string itself .. I did it to achieve the purpose of comparing the string dates